# Three JS models for OpenGL

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, three.js

I am trying to use the Three JS format for 3D models in my LWJGL game because of the easy to use JSON format, but I can't quite figure out how it's displaying vertices and indices. It has a "vertices":[] array and a "faces":[] array, and I thought that the faces were the indices like in the obj format, but that isn't the case. I don't know what the faces do, because for a cube that should only have 8 vertices it had like a number 40 in the faces array. Where are the indices for glDrawElements?

Comment: [This format?](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3)

Comment: Yes, that looks to be it. Now that I see it I have been looking at it completely wrong. I'm still a little confused though, can someone clarify how it works a little more?